# Optimizing interpolation in Mathematica

Tags: optimization, wolfram-mathematica, interpolation

As part of my work, I often have to visualize complex 3 dimensional densities.  One program suite that I work with outputs the radial component of the densities as a set of 781 points on a logarithmic grid, `ri = (Rmax/Rstep)^((i-1)/(pts-1)`, times a spherical harmonic.  For low symmetry systems, the number of spherical harmonics can be fairly large to ensure accuracy, e.g. one system requires 49 harmonics corresponding to `lmax = 6`.  So, to use this data within Mathematica, I would have a sum of up to 49 interpolated functions with each multiplied by a different spherical harmonic.  While using v.6 and constructing the interpolated radial functions using `Interpolation` and setting `r = Sqrt(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)`, I would stop  `ContourPlot3D` after well over an hour without anything displayed.  This included reducing both the `InterpolationOrder` and `MaxRecursion` to 1.

Several alternatives presented themselves:

1. Evaluate the density function on a fixed grid, and use `ListContourPlot` instead.
2. Or, linearly spline the radial function and use `Piecewise` to stitch them together.  (This presented itself, as I could use simplify to help reduce the complexity of the resulting function.)

I ended up using both, as `InterpolatingFunction` gives a noticeable delay in its evaluation, and with up to 49 interpolated functions to evaluate, any delay can become noticeable. Also, `ContourPlot3D` was faster with the spline, but it didn't give me the speed up I desired.

I'll freely admit that I haven't tried `Interpolation` on v.7, nor I have tried this on my upgraded hardware (G4 v. Intel Core i5).  However, I'm looking for alternatives to my current scheme; preferably, one where I can use `ContourPlot3D` directly.  I could try some other form of spline, such as a [B-spline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-spline), and possibly combine that with `UnitBox` instead of using `Piecewise`.

**Edit:** Just to clarify, my current implementation involves creating a first order spline for each radial part, multiplying each one by their respective spherical harmonic, summing and `Simplify`ing the equations on each radial interval, and then using `Piecewise` to bind them into one function.  So, my implementation is semi-analytical in that the spherical harmonics are exact, and only the radial part is numerical.  This is part of the reason why I would like to be able to use `ContourPlot3D`, so that I can take advantage of the semi-analytical nature of the data.  As a point of note, the radial grid is fine enough that a good representation of the radial part is generated and can be smoothly interpolated.  While this gave me a significant speed-up, when I wrote the code, it was still to slow for the hardware I was using at the time.

So, instead of using `ContourPlot3D`, I would first generate the function, as above, then I would evaluate it on an 80<sup>3</sup> Cartesian grid.  It is the data from this step that I used in `ListContourPlot3D`.  Since this is not an adaptive grid, in some places this was too course, and I was missing features.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand you correctly: you have 781 data points on each radial function for a total of 781*49 scalars?

Comment: Are you using `DataRange` and data only for `ListContourPlot` -- otherwise it looks like there is an internal layer of interpolation, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497517/mathematica-listcontourplot3d

Comment: @Janus, yes, you read that correctly.  There are up to 781*49 scalars.  As I pointed out above, the angular part of the data is analytical, and only the radial part is numerical.  Also, I have run into the low resolution bug for data in the `{x,y,z,f}` form when using `ListContourPlot3D` before, but here I've generated a 3D array and specified the `DataRange`.  Additionally, while slow, the internal layer of interpolation in `ListContourPlot3D` is still faster than `ContourPlot3D`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it really is the interpolation of the radial functions that is slowing you down, you could consider hand-coding that part based on your knowledge of the sample points. As demonstrated below, this gives a significant speedup:

I set things up with your notation. `lookuprvals` is a list of 100000 `r` values to look up for timing.

First, look at stock interpolation as a basemark

```
With[{interp=Interpolation[N@Transpose@{rvals,yvals}]},
  Timing[interp[lookuprvals]][[1]]]
Out[259]= 2.28466
```

Switching to 0th-order interpolation is already an order of magnitude faster (first order is almost same speed):

```
With[{interp=Interpolation[N@Transpose@{rvals,yvals},InterpolationOrder->0]},
  Timing[interp[lookuprvals]][[1]]]
Out[271]= 0.146486
```

We can get another 1.5 order of magnitude by calculating indices directly:

```
Module[{avg=MovingAverage[yvals,2],idxfact=N[(pts-1) /Log[Rmax/Rstep]]},
  Timing[res=Part[avg,Ceiling[idxfact Log[lookuprvals]]]][[1]]]
Out[272]= 0.006067
```

As a middle ground, do a log-linear interpolation by hand. This is slower than the above solution but still much faster than stock interpolation:

```
Module[{diffs=Differences[yvals],
  idxfact=N[(pts-1) /Log[Rmax/Rstep]]},
  Timing[Block[{idxraw,idxfloor,idxrel},
    idxraw=1+idxfact Log[lookuprvals];
    idxfloor=Floor[idxraw];
    idxrel=idxraw-idxfloor;
    res=Part[yvals,idxfloor]+Part[diffs,idxfloor]idxrel  
  ]][[1]]]
Out[276]= 0.026557
```

If you have the memory for it, I would cache the spherical harmonics and radius (or even radius-index) on the full grid. Then flatten the grid caches so you can do

```
 Sum[ interpolate[yvals[lm],gridrvals] gridylmvals[lm], {lm,lmvals} ]
```

and recreate your grid as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3807976/inverse-of-flatten-in-mathematica).

Comment: sorry it took me so long to look at this.  In your third example, you calc the moving avg, but then don't do anything with it.  Also, calculating the indices and using `Part` is clever, and essentially what I was thinking of doing.  I already `Compile` the functions, but maybe this can be done reasonably well with a dispatch table.  I'm not sure how well 0th order would work for what I want to do, but if it is effective, that would provide a great speed up.  Lots to think about, and as it is a side project at the moment, it will be while before I can implement it.  Thanks for thoughts.

Comment: Changed example 3 to what I had in mind: to return the mean of the endpoint values on each interval. Looking at this again, it occurred to me that it might actually be worth oversampling your radial data (via a spline or something) just to allow you to do the fast 0th order interpolation when you are sampling on the grid?

Answer (score 5):

If you can do without Mathematica, I would suggest you have a look at [Paraview](http://www.paraview.org/) (US government funded FOSS, all platforms) which I have found to be superior to everything when it comes to visualizing massive amounts of data.
The core of the software is the "Visualization Toolkit" [VTK](http://www.vtk.org/), and you can find/write other frontends if need be.

VTK/Paraview can handle almost any data-type: scalar and vector on structured grids or random points, polygons, time-series data, etc. From Mathematica I often just dump grid data into VTK [legacy format](http://www.vtk.org/VTK/img/file-formats.pdf) which in then simplest case looks like this

```
# vtk DataFile Version 2.0
Generated by mma via vtkGridDump

ASCII

DATASET STRUCTURED_POINTS
DIMENSIONS 49 25 15
SPACING 0.125 0.125 0.0625
ORIGIN 8.5 5. 0.7124999999999999

POINT_DATA 18375
SCALARS  RF_pondpot_1V1MHz1amu  double 1
LOOKUP_TABLE default

0.04709501616121583
0.04135197485227461
... <18373 more numbers> ...
```

HTH!

Comment: +1, I had run across those in the past, but at the time the learning curve was enough that I avoided them.  They are definitely industrial strength solutions, and I may have to resort to them eventually.  But, I was hoping for a Mathematica based solution, as it is what I know best and the time to implement would be, at worst, several hours.